# What is the minimum version of svn (server) compatible with git-svn

Tags: git, svn, compatibility, tortoisegit

I am trying to run git-svn using TortoiseGit and am having problems (405 Method not allowed) and am wondering if the problem is that the svn server is too old (svn 1.3). Is there any documented compatibility list of git-svn and svn server?

Comment: it turns out that the root cause of the error was an authentication problem with cached credentials.

Comment: Thank you for this feedback. I have updated my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SVN server 1.3 should be able to be accessed by any client (including a tortoiseGit) even recent. See [SVN Compatibility Matrix](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/compatibility.html)

The error message may be rather related to a similar error [seen with TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/faq.html#four05).
It reference the [HTTP error page](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> 10.4.6 **405 Method Not Allowed**
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested resource.

---

Almost: [Ken Liu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/25688/ken-liu) (the OP) does mention in his comment:

> it turns out that the root cause of the error was an **authentication problem with cached credentials**.